# How to navigate and pass data between UIViewControllers whose layout resembles a fork?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a couple of `UIViewControllers` like shown

[image: Fork Layout]

What I want is to pass data **from B to C** and also do that transition. So far I've come with 2 possible solutions:

1. Create a new instance of the C `UIViewController` class (and save a reference of the data in it), pop B from the `navigation controller` and push C into it.
2. Send the data to A, pop B from the `navigation controller` and then, in the `viewWillAppear` method of A, check if the data is not nil to know if it should send it to C and perform the `segue`.

Should I take any of those 2 approaches? Or is there a more elegant/proper solution for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: It's its own view controller

Comment: I don't understand. A pushes to B? And from B you want to transition to C?

Comment: The scenario is that I came from A to B, and now I want to go from B to C but also pass some data

Comment: You already accepted an answer but going forward, try to be more precise with your language. Coming from A to B and then going from B to C doesn't mean anything. Are you pushing or presenting? Is A a parent of B and C and you are transitioning between children? Is A its own view controller and the user can push to B or C? It doesn't matter now, but learn the terminology, it will help greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organize data manager of parent controller or use Core Data.

In case of keeping data in parent controller, use dependency injection like described [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dependency-injection-in-view-controllers-9fd7d2c77e55)

Here is an example for your case:

```
var dataFromC = "" // or nil
var dataFromB = "" // or nil

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "B",
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? BViewController {
        viewController.dataFromC = self.dataFromC

//           declare method in BViewController
//           var method : ((String) -> ())? = nil
        viewController.method = {[weak self] valueFromB in
            self?.dataFromB = valueFromB
        }
    }

    if segue.identifier == "C",
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? CViewController {
        viewController.dataFromB = self.dataFromB

//           declare method in CViewController
//           var method : ((String) -> ())? = nil
        viewController.method = {[weak self] valueFromC in
            self?.dataFromC = valueFromC
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pass value to parent controller from `BViewController`, use `self.method("yourValueFromB")` where you will change the value. For case with `CViewController` use same approach.

Comment: So it would be like the second approach I posted?

Comment: Yes. There is so many ways to do it. The example above uses dependency injection and here passed function (`closure`) from parent controller `method`. Also you can wrap it to protocols or handler objects. All of combinations are work.

Answer (score 1):

As a general practice, B should send the data back to its originating view controller A with the help of delegate protocol pattern. A should be able to then decide in the delegate method implementation, what the data is received from B and where to send this data, which in this case is C.

This way your code looks more organised.